# How to appens nodes using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

Hi everyone I'm using XPATH with XML.SelectNodes() to extract dome data from an XML file, I wish this data to be in certain order, the XML file is like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <ConvenioAladi>
       <Operaciones>
         <Operacion Prioridad='Alta' />
         <Operacion Prioridad='Media' />
         <Operacion Prioridad='Alta' />
         <Operacion Prioridad='Baja' />
         <Operacion Prioridad='Baja' />
         <Operacion Prioridad='Media' />
       </Operaciones>
    </ConvenioAladi>
```

And wish to obtain an XML like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <ConvenioAladi>
       <Operaciones>
         <Operacion Prioridad='Alta' />
         <Operacion Prioridad='Alta' />
         <Operacion Prioridad='Media' />
         <Operacion Prioridad='Media' />
         <Operacion Prioridad='Baja' />
         <Operacion Prioridad='Baja' />
       </Operaciones>
    </ConvenioAladi>
```

I'm capable of obtaining one of the Prioridad attributes at any moment by giving the XPATH:

**'/ConvenioAladi/Operaciones/Operacion[@Prioridad='Alta']'**,

but if I try something like this:
**'/ConvenioAladi/Operaciones/Operacion[@Prioridad='Alta' or @Prioridad='Media' or @Prioridad='Baja' ]'**

Or:
**'/ConvenioAladi/Operaciones/Operacion[@Prioridad='Alta'] | /ConvenioAladi/Operaciones/Operacion[@Prioridad='Media'] | /ConvenioAladi/Operaciones/Operacion[@Prioridad='Baja']'**

I always get the original XML back, is there anyway of achieving what I mentioned before?. Thanks

Comment: Why not look for the next sibling with the same attribute value and a greater position?

Comment: Seems like you are using XPath 1. There it is impossible. It only returns a set of nodes, not a sequence

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams How could I do that, could you make an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath in the version you are using matches nodes in order, which you cannot change.

There are several ways to achieve it:

## XSLT

One simple way is to perform an [XSL Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)

Once you learn XSLT, it becomes really easy to do this sort of thing. Such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="Operaciones">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Operacion">
                <xsl:sort select="index-of(('Alta','Media','Baja'), @Prioridad)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And then you can query all your `Operaciones` easily. If you do it the XSLT route, it means that you can upgrade your queries without having to recompile your software. It is probably the solution you wish to utilise.

**Update: Mathias pointed out that we're not looking for an alphabetical sort. I will keep the solutions below for reference, but now I'd advise to go for the correct XSLT solution above.**

## XPathDocument

The second way is more programatic, which utilises Microsoft's own features:

Assuming `doc` is an `XmlDocument`, you can do the following to turn it into an `XPathDocument`:

```
XPathDocument xpathDoc = new XPathDocument(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
```

Once you do that, you can run the following query:

```
XPathNavigator nav = xpathDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression expression = XPathExpression.Compile(@"//Operacion");
expression.AddSort(@"@Prioridad", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Text);
XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expression);
foreach (XPathNavigator operation in iterator) {
    Console.WriteLine("Found priority '{0}'",operation.GetAttribute("Prioridad",""));
}
```

## Linq

Third way, using Linq (you might want to check the syntax here):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
var operations = xDoc.Descendants("Operacion").OrderBy(s=>(string)s.Attribute("Prioridad"));
foreach(var operation in operations) {
    Console.WriteLine("hey -> {0}", operation);
}
```

I suggest you do it via Linq, but if you are transforming data, then go for XSLT every time.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but your XSLT code was not visible until now, and it's not quite correct. The standard sort is alphabetical, which is not useful in this case. You'd have to `apply-templates` separately: http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQD.

Comment: Thank you @MathiasMüller for pointing these issues out, very much appreciated! I updated the XSLT with a more idiomatic way - still using a single sort.

Comment: plus 1, but be aware that this will only work in XSLT 2.0, since `index-of()` is a 2.0 function: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTF.

Comment: Updated version attribute to 2.0. Works on Saxon 9.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed before, there are a few options here.  For the sake of concreteness, here's a complete XSLT (1.0) solution, which has so far only been hinted at:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="name (.)"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$n}">
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ConvenioAladi"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Operaciones">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Operacion[@Prioridad = &quot;Alta&quot;]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Operacion[@Prioridad = &quot;Media&quot;]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Operacion[@Prioridad = &quot;Baja&quot;]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can apply this stylesheet to your XML and it sorts the `Operacion` nodes in the order `Alta`, `Media`, `Baja`.  It proceeds rather naively: it simply looks for any `Operacion` having the value `Alta` for the `Prioridad` attribute, and (essentially) copies it to the output.  Then `Media`, then `Baja`.  It would work even if there are no `Operacion` nodes having value `Baja` for their `Prioridad` attribute (and similarly for the other two values).  The stylesheet does assume, implicitly, that these three are the only possible values for the `Prioridad` attribute (if there are such nodes, they are silently ignored), so if you have `Operacion` nodes that might have other values for their `Prioridad` attribute, the stylesheet would need to be adjusted.

Comment: Please stop posting bad XSLT answers. Your code works, but it's laden with unnecessary constructs - elements from the output can be _copied_ to the output, no need to generate new elements. No need to `for-each` over a list of known attributes from the input. No need to escape quotes in XSLT if you are using them as actual quotes.

Comment: That said, the XSLT code (not visible until recently)  in the accepted answer to this question is wrong - the standard sort alphabetical, which is useless in this case. So, everybody would really profit from a useful XSLT answer, along the lines of http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQD.